# VB.Net Create Database table from class property

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create an inheritable class(OF t) in vb.net that I will pass it a class of objects.  Inside the class of objects I want to use the class properties to create a corresponding database table.  Like below

```
Public Class SampleClass

#Region "Properties"
Private newPropertyValue As String
Public Property NewProperty() As String
    Get
        Return newPropertyValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        newPropertyValue = value
    End Set
End Property
#End Region

Public Sub New()

End Sub

End Class
```

I'm new to vb.net so I don't know my way around exactly.

I was looking into class attributes for this action but they do not fully make sense to me yet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to get well versed on something called [Code First](https://www.google.com/#q=code+first). This should get you started.